# How to Take Input from user in pytube?

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I tried taking url from user but pytube opens up the video in web browser

modules-Pytube3
python version-3.7.6
Here is the code-

```
from pytube import YouTube
a = str(input())
yt = YouTube(a)
yt.streams.first().download()
```

a is variable to take input from user

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me with version 10.0.0 of pytube

```
import pytube
print("Give URL:")
url = input()
youtube = pytube.YouTube(url)
video = youtube.streams.get_highest_resolution().download('../Video')
```

I think pytube is very active maybe try updating it?

More [here](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)